# I have added "Previous Quarter" in jquery datatable but i am not getting the expected result

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

[image]

If todays date is 19/Feb/2020 then i want the Previous Quarter to be set as 1/Oct/2019 to 31/Dec/2019 what should be in code to make it possible i tried

`var quarter = moment().quarter();
dateRange['Previous Quarter'] = [moment().quarter(quarter).endOf('quarter')];`

Here "Previous Quarter"  represents "the quarter before the current quarter" .

Answer (score 0):

//Selects the quarter before the current quarter.

dateRange['Previous Quarter'] = [moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').startOf('quarter'), moment().subtract(1, 'quarter').endOf('quarter')];

it works!!

[image]